# Need help figuring how to write a multidimentional array to store names by letter

Tags: java, arrays

I am currently working on a project with a lot of different componenets but one of them is really stumping me. I have to wrte a mutltidimensional array that stores a list of names. The names are are already in a single dimensional array and have been sorted into alphabetical order. For the multidimentioal array I need to store all the names that begin with A in the first set, all the names that begin with B in the second, and so on. I know I can use the ASCII value of the charachters to keep track of the first postion by subrtacting 65 from the value of the letter in the first position of the name and setting that equal to i for array[i] but I don't really know how to store the name after that. Needless to say, I'm really confused and can hardly even say what it is I need. Any help at all is appreciated I haven't written any code yet because I dont't know what to write

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) as the second dimension of the array. That way you can arbitrarily add any number of strings. Here is a sample to give you some ideas

```
    ArrayList<String>[] nameList = new ArrayList[25];
    for(int i =0; i < nameList.length; i++){
        nameList[i] = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    String[] names = {"Ali","Joe","Sue","Jane"};
    for(int i = 0; i < names.length;i++){
        int firstLetterCharacterCode = names[i].charAt(0) - 65;
        nameList[firstLetterCharacterCode].add(names[i]);
    }

    for(int i =0; i < nameList.length;i++){
        for(String name : nameList[i]){
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
```

If your feeling bold you can look into [maps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). It would make accessing a particular set of names list more elegant since you could use the letter of the key.

Comment: thanks for the help, I actually managed to figure it out in another way using a similar set-up. First I used an array of all the names in alphabetical order to set the first index [i] then I used an array that stored the frequency of the first initial of each of the names to set the second index [j].